# How to place relative divs below absolute ones?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

I have a background image and over that a carousel with text and an image both 1024x287px.
I want to add more info below that image and underneath I want to place the footer.

I can solve this with just a px margin on top, but once you're-size the browser it looks bad.

I have the following markup:

```css
.img-background {
  @media (max-width: 1035px) {
    display: none;
  }
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:50%;
  left:-512px;
  top:0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.infoblock {
  z-index: 2;
}

.carousel-control.right {
  left: auto;
  right: -50px;
}

.carousel-control.left {
  left: -100px;
  right: auto;
}

.carousel {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 50%;
  left: -512px;
  top: 60px;
  z-index: 2;
}

wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.carousel .item {
  width: 100%;
  /*slider width*/
  height: auto;
  /*slider height*/
  z-index: 2;
}

.carousel .item img {
  @media (max-width: 1035px) {
    display: none;
  }
  margin-left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  /*img width*/
}

/*full width container*/

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .block {
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
  }
}

@import 'bootstrap-responsive';
.navbar-inner {
  @include box-shadow(none !important);
  border: 0;
}

.navbar .nav>li>a {
  padding: 25px 10px 5px
}

.footer {
  color: $grayLight;
  a {
    color: $gray;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="block wrapper">

  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <img class="img-background" src="assets/banner.png" alt="">
      <div class="active item">
        <img src="assets/banner_1.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="assets/banner_2.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="assets/banner_3.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="assets/banner_4.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="assets/banner_5.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="assets/banner_6.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
      <img class="img" src="assets/android.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="img" src="assets/iphone.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <img class="img" src="assets/landline.png" alt="">
    <div>
      <img class="img" src="assets/blackberry.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="img" src="assets/windows.png" alt="">
    </div>

  </div>

</section>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 5000
    })

  });
</script>
```

This is how it's not supposed to look like:

[image: EZ-Call Home]

The problem with placing the Android, iPhone, etc. logos in the carousel is that when you downsize the browser they're all the way to the left, so invisible.

How can I place a div just underneath the carousel and when the screen is small, the carousel is not showing, so it should just be on top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can not place two relatively positioned DIV's on top of each other, to my knowledge, at least.

What you can do, is use absolute positioning of the images, inside a relatively positioned DIV. 
Take a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enbs/Q4qNC/2/), I made earlier.

The Red DIV is semi-transparent and on top of the Blue DIV, using `position: absolute;`, `top: 0;`, `left: 0;`, these two are placed, inside a container `<div class="container">` with `position: relative;` and `margin: 0 auto;` to center the container.

Comment: I ended up placing the same image relative behind the absolute one, I couldn't get the container to work.

Comment: Be sure to copy the css, exactly the way it is in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enbs/Q4qNC/4/). It'll work.